# how to avoid to send null value into sql in java

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have table with 35 columns where the entries like 
  day1,day2,day3 ------ upto day31 .
  I have defined these 31 columns with null allow accepted.
  I am inserting record using JdbcTemplate  Method
     update(String sql, Object... args) throws DataAccessException
  which column is not having value or blank .. null value is inserted into table ..that is fine.

but when I update the table which column is already having some value but 
  current json entry contains blank value for that column then that column value become null.
  and I want to make addition of 31 fields in which are having integer values.

Answer (score 3):

Your current table design seems suboptimal, and I would instead suggest having a separate *record* for each day of the month.  Better yet, just maintain a single date column, and then have another column for the quantity you want to sum:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (dt date, quantity int, ...);
```

The icing on the cake here is that now if you want to sum by date, or range of dates, you need only use the `SUM()` function, which by default will *ignore* `NULL` values.  So, it doesn't matter whether your empty placeholders be zero or `NULL`, the result would be the same.

Comment: but how can i use it in java?

Comment: @JacobH what do you mean by?

Comment: @Polyglotcoders The answer speaks for itself.  Fix your table design and data model, and the problem in your original question basically goes away.